# Can a system reach equilibrium using only reversible processes?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Consider an isolated system. We know that it will reach equilibrium after enough time. According to what I have read so far, the system should undergo irreversible processes to reach equilibrium, but is there any counterexample to this statement? i.e a system and a nonequilibrium initial condition such that processes used to reach equilibrium are all reversible?

Comment: Not if the system is isolated.

Comment: @ChetMiller Why? and what is an example if it is not isolated?

Comment: Well, if it is not isolated, then you can make the process reversible by exchanging heat and work reversibly with the surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

Assume an isolated system. Start from an equilibrium state $0$ and remove some internal constraint so that the system spontaneously moves to *another* equilibrium state $1$. The difference in entropy $\Delta S = S_1 - S_0$ between the entropies of the final $S_1$ and initial $S_0$ is never negative (2nd law), and it is positive for an irreversible process the amount being characteristic and a measure of irreversibility.

Comment: I think the OP is saying the isolated system starts out in disequilibrium.

Comment: @Bob_D That is OK, just measure the entropy variation at any instant *after* the system is allowed to equilibrate and has left state $0$.